# How to convert database table record to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am learning php and doing a small project. I have a city_name table in database with columns id, name, longitude and latitude. It might have 10-15 rows at best. Now when user load index.php I do this query to get all data from the city_name table

```
$city_name = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM city_name');
```

Values found from the above query, I want to create a javascript variable in following format. I want to do this in the same index.php inside  tag.

```
var locations = [
    ['IMaxx', 50.780941, 6.079134],
    ['Aachen-Elisenbrunnen', 50.771680, 6.086472],
    ['Uni-Cinema', 50.776185, 6.079306],
    ['Alter-Posthof', 50.771705, 6.086561],
    ['Cinemaxx', 50.770754, 6.084942]
];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: As you're just learning PHP, it would be beneficial to you to avoid things like [mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Simply echo it as JSON string:

```
<?php
$arrayFromDB = [
    ['IMaxx', 50.780941, 6.079134],
    ['Aachen-Elisenbrunnen', 50.771680, 6.086472],
    ['Uni-Cinema', 50.776185, 6.079306],
    ['Alter-Posthof', 50.771705, 6.086561],
    ['Cinemaxx', 50.770754, 6.084942]
];

echo "<script>var locations = ".json_encode($arrayFromDB).";</script>";
?>
```

Comment: @DavidePastore why it's not valid?

Comment: On phpfiddle.org it gives me `Message : syntax error, unexpected '['`.

Comment: I have to format the values of $city_name as above also. How can I do that?

Comment: @DavidePastore Maybe there is old PHP version, that does not support shorthand array (`[]` instead of `array()`?

Comment: @asdlfkjlkj Please explain what you need. Basically you take any array and pass it to `json_encode`.

Comment: @Justinas You're right. As you can see [here](http://3v4l.org/c6JeE), it gives errors for 5.3 release. [Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).